# How can I run a Program, and have it continue when the remote console disconnects

Tags: linux, shell-script, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to run my Java Program, but it needs to continue running even if i close Putty.
The Program is running on my Raspberry pi and it is starting completely fine,
but as soon as I close the console the Program stops.

Currently I tried it with an sh script and this line within it:

`nohup java -jar /home/pi/Programms/PantaBot/PantaBot.jar  > /var/log/logPantaBot.txt 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to say what operating system/distro you are running here. Assuming it's something using systemd then add a new file in /etc/systemd/system (e.g. pantabot.service) containing something like...

```
[Unit]
Description=pantabot

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java \
  -jar /home/pi/Programms/PantaBot/PantaBot.jar 

SuccessExitStatus=143
```

It's generally good practice to have your log files managed automatically - adding the following to the [Service] section will add the logs to your existing (rotated) log files....

```
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
```

But you can send it to a specific file too.

```
StandardOutput=append:var/log/logPantaBot.txt
StandardError=append:var/log/logPantaBot.txt
```

Once done, run `systemctl daemon-reload` then use systemctl start pantabot / systemctl stop pantabot to control it.

Finally, if you append

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and run `systemctl enable pantabot` it will start up automatically when you fire up the host.

Comment: I have never needed to get the init process involved. Well that depends: If you just want to start a batch process, and have it finish after you logout, then there is no need to involve the init process. If you want to run a long running service, then maybe you should.